# Custom allocator for LDLT

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Is there a way to supply raw buffers for the LDLT class in the same way that raw buffers can be used for the Matrix classes (like https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html)?

Even if I do an in-place LDLT on a mapped matrix, then the transpositions will be allocated on the regular C++ heap.

The issue is in the application I'm working on we need to use a custom allocator.

If there's not a supported way of doing this, what might be the easiest way to work around this? Could I subclass LDLT and just take over the allocation of the different heap variables? That might be easier to maintain than trying to pull the data out of the LDLT class and reproducing the solve code elsewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: For the factorization itself, you could call `internal::ldlt_inplace<UpLo>::unblocked(my_matrix, my_transpositions, my_temporary, my_sign)` but I cannot think about an easy solution to reuse the `LDLT::_solve_imp` without changing Eigen itself.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What I've ended up doing is just pulling out the matrix, the diagonal, and the transpositions and saved them. Then I more or less copy-pasted `LDLT::_solve_imp` and have it reference these other data structures. Not great, but whatevs.

Comment: Just to be clear... Not great what I've done, Eigen itself is excellent, thanks!